# Laravel Eloquent `having` with calculated column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following logic in my controller, and it fails at the `having` statement. Without the `$type` step the data shows as expected (so the `addSelect` works as expected). How do I filter with `having` using the calculated column `meters_count`?

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "meters_count" does not exist
```

The code:

```
// Get all customers visible to this user
$query = Site::with('customer.logo', 'mainContact', 'address')
    ->addSelect(['meters_count' => Meter::selectRaw('COUNT(*)')->whereColumn('meters.site_id', 'sites.id')]);

// Filter for user type
switch ($type) {

    case 'deleted':
        $query->onlyTrashed();
        break;

    case 'no_meters':
        $query->groupBy('sites.id')
           ->having('meters_count', '=', 0);
        break;

    default:
        $query->groupBy('sites.id')
           ->having('meters_count', '>', 0);
}

// Run query here...
$sites = $query-get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
// Get all customers visible to this user
$query = Site::with('customer.logo', 'mainContact', 'address')
    ->withCount('meters');

// Filter for user type
switch ($type) {

   case 'deleted':
        $query->onlyTrashed();
        break;

   case 'no_meters':
        $query->groupBy('sites.id')
            ->havingRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM meters WHERE meters.site_id = sites.id) = ?', [0]);
        break;

   default:
        $query->groupBy('sites.id')
            ->havingRaw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM meters WHERE meters.site_id = sites.id) > ?', [0]);
    }

}

// Run query here...
$sites = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply GroupBy function before apply having

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->groupBy('account_id')
                ->having('account_id', '>', 100)
                ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries